# How to generate DTM from a DSM (having 12.5 meter accuracy)?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem

The data that I have is an open-source DEM having a spatial resolution of 12.5 meters.
Now I want to generate the DTM out of it.
Is there any algorithm or model available to extract DTM out of DEM (using open-source or ArcGIS software)?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, 12.5 m accuracy is a bad start to create a good bare earth surface (DTM) from an elevation model (DEM). One would say it's impossible.

Below some hints and warning if you want to try nevertheless.

---

**Hand made**

You could try using an external source (like vector based layers) to **clip out the areas you spot as cars, trees, building, or more generally things you estimate are not on the ground**.

You will then  obtain a DEM with holes, with only ground areas. You will need to reinterpolate your DEM in the NoData areas with a reinterpolation technique  from the DEM converted into a point cloud or directly from the holed DEM with NoData filling tools (Saga GIS, open source, has a fill gaps module). It will then create something looking like a DTM model.

**WARNING :** Beware that this technique would works efficiently if the erased areas are **small** and if the **elevation changes are small**. Should you try this in thick forest areas (like in Canada), you would obtain nothing really usable (erasing 80% of your DEM seems a bit useless...). Same thing in places where there is a lot of elevation change, the reinterpolation would just cut off the topography.

---

**Automatic method**

The tools exists for LIDAR based point cloud and has reference on how to do this (for example [lasground](https://rapidlasso.com/lastools/lasground/)) - which is not open source but usable for a try. For Arcgis based solutions, you could have a look here : [ESRI LIDAR Tools help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/using-lidar-in-arcgis.htm).

You would have to cheat and convert your DEM data in .las format. Then you could put in trough those tools, but i strongly doubt it works as efficiently as with LIDAR data, because a DEM like yours has not the same point density and is not made the same way : **LIDAR point cloud have ground point mixed with higher points**, and the tools mentioned before are specifically made to spot these areas, whereas DEM are often a continuous surface, probably interpolated from other raw data.